# Full RSS feeds for Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types

I would like my Custom Post Types to bee full text feeds, with the whole content.
This url of course works http://sitename.com/feed/?post_type=name, but I only get excerpts in the feed. Regardless of setting feeds to be full text in Panel Settings.

I know there is snippets for including the Custom Post Types feed to the main feed. But I want separate feeds to be full content feeds.

Thankful for help

Answer (score 2):

This is browser issue and not an issue with WordPress. WordPress will obey the setting in Reading Settings option screen.

The Full text is not shown on Firefox and Google Chrome. That is the way Firefox and Google Chrome works.

I have tried to it on IE and it works. I don't have other browsers installed here to check if it works on other browsers.

Comment: Ah, of course. Didn't even think of that. My bad. Thank you!